# How to translate connection on four graphs to quantum 6j symbols

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories

I need the explicit quantum 6j symbols for the Haagerup fusion category for a physics research project. This paper [math/9803044](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803044) by Asaeda and Haagerup brute-force constructs the Haagerup subfactor, by giving explicit connections on four graphs. So I wonder: (1) Is the data of connections equivalent to the quantum 6j symbols? (2) If so, how can I translate?

Any help or direction to references is very much appreciated!

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes.  I don't know of a reference for your second question, but probably such a reference exists.  If no one else addresses the second question, I'll attempt an answer.

Comment: Your base problem is that you need the 6j-symbols. I have those sitting around if you email me.

Comment: @KevinWalker, thanks for your answer. Though I currently just need the Haagerup 6j-symbols that Matthew has offered, I am very interested in learning about the general relation between connections and 6j symbols.

Comment: That email is dead, but my Gmail should be in my ArXiv papers.